# Display the size of each email/conversation in Gmail

Tags: gmail

My Gmail inbox shows 9 columns: a box to select the conversation, star, "important" tag, name of who sent the email, subject, archive, delete, mark as unread, and snooze.

I cannot find a way to customize the inbox window to show the number of kilobytes or megabytes that the e-mail takes.

Anyone know how to add a column to display the conversation size?

I do not want to know how to search by size.  I want to add a column of the size in my inbox.

Comment: Gmail, by itself, doesn't allow for much customization. To truly do what you want, you'd need to use a third-party email client.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like that is possible at the moment. But that would be a great feature request to the Gmail team.

In the mean time you could try a work around. You can use a Google Sheet that connects to your Gmail to allow you to view/filter and sort by email size. The sheet is called *Gmail Sort by ctrlq.org*

How To:

1. Copy google sheet to your Google Drive from this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DKhqTClj4ATMqEKwr0kM86ZOD6de3Vh__zs2QtYYriM/copy)
2. From top menu select `Gmail Sort > Scan Mailbox`
3. The script will require authorization to scan your Gmail inbox. It is an open source script created by ctrlq.org (check it out [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19040-gmail-size-search?_ga=2.97822875.564121517.1560050657-1848863235.1560050657))

Check out this post for more info: [Sort Gmail Messages by Size](https://www.labnol.org/internet/sort-gmail-by-size/21191/)

Comment: +1. My answer just elaborates a bit.

Comment: this is gonna take _a while_!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to be able to view the size of each email conversation like it can be done in some email clients, such as this one:

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be possible in Gmail. One instead has to search "size:5242880" to list emails of size 5242880 bytes (for example). Perhaps Gmail is trying to make it difficult for people to clean out their inboxes after reaching the 15GB limit, which forces them to upgrade to a premium account .